# Custom values under css property - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I was just streaming some videos in youtube, and suddenly I felt curious on checking the HTML structure of the youtube. And I noticed some cool things going on.

Most of the HTML tags used aren't the standard tags, well I have some knowledge on the Angular where we can define the our own HTML tags. But which I couldn't understand was passing some custom values in the CSS properties.

Like this one:

```
background: var(--yt-dialog-background);
```

[image]

Does any one know like how these things work? I'm just curious to know about it, and it's not just background. For several properties, I see there are custom values under it. And I even tried to go a bit deeper, like finding the `var(--yt-dialog-background)` under the elements in the inspector, but I couldn't find any values corresponding to `var(--yt-dialog-background)`

Comment: This question is quite broad imho, but this might get you started: https://htmlmag.com/article/an-introduction-to-css-preprocessors-sass-less-stylus

Comment: But those pre-processors transform their own syntax into regular CSS, unless I'm mistaken. How did the variable name itself make it into the inspector?

Comment: You might need to check the MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables):

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: green;
}

div {
  color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some text
</div>
```

Comment: Man, that's so cool. I never knew CSS had variables. I use SASS for my CSS. But these variables have any advantage over the variables I use in SASS?

Comment: @UnknownUser Yep, you can change the value of these variables through Javascript. See the very last example in the MDN article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing are the native [css variables.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) [Browser support is actually pretty good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables), which is why you're seeing them being used in production by a website like YouTube.

Basic use looks like the following:

```
:root {
    --main-color: red;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--main-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing there are not custom values but native css variables.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

The support is quite good for modern browsers:

https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variable